# Postman can't get access to the file into folder

Tags: rest, http, request, postman, httprequest

I want send request with file to server, but when I try nested file to, [image]

in settings I turn up reading files outside working directory, but it doesn't work.
I using Opera browser.

[image]

What's the matter?

Comment: What are the permissions for the folder and file?